# Collection::stream usage

Tags: java

I want to convert a mixed object stream into a flat list.

This code work fine:

```
    List<List<String>> list2 = Arrays.asList(
            Arrays.asList("a", "b"),
            Arrays.asList("c", "d"));
    System.out.println(list2
            .stream()
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

However, if I write the following code:

```
    List<? extends Object> list3 = Arrays.asList(
            Arrays.asList("a", "b"),
            Arrays.asList("c", "d"),
            Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("e", "f"), "g"));
    System.out.println(list3
            .stream()
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

I got error message: "Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context".

How do I properly use flatMap in this case?

Comment: Please at least google for the error message before posting.

Comment: BTW the first code snippet will also not work if the list is declared as `List<? extends Object> list2` (since `Collection::stream` [in that *context*] needs an instance of  `Collection`)

Comment: try `List<List<?>> list3 = ...`  (despite it will only *flatten* one level)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish via `flatMap(Collection::stream)`? You've already called that method, via `list3.stream()`. Your code doesn't make sense.